# Specify distance between nodes in Networkx

Tags: python, networking, networkx

I need to create a network out of correlation matrix, I would like the nodes that are highly correlated to be closer to each other and vice versa

I tried to create my network like following

```
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('A', 'C', weight=0.5)
G.add_edge('A', 'D', weight=0)
G.add_edge('A', 'E', weight=0)
G.add_edge('A', 'F', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('A', 'G', weight=-0.2)
```

But the network does not seem accurate in the sense that the distance between nodes do not reflect the correlation

Is there any easy fix for setting up in advance the distance between the nodes ?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `nx.layout.spectral_layout`?

Comment: Yes I did but the network doesn't look accurate